# Preparing JSON tree structure from a JSON javascript

Tags: javascript

am looking for a JSON tree from a plain JSON.
below is the Input and expected output json.
the input json doesnt have any order
There can be multiple items at each level and each item can have n number of childrens.
leafFlag = 0 means no children
leafFlag = 1 means has chidlren
path is the property which tells where the item will be placed
The expectedOutputJson needs to be placed in a table to display level wise data

```js
var inputJson = [
  {
  "level": "1",
  "leafFlag": "1",
  "path":"p123",
  "name":"food"
},
  {
  "level": "1",
  "leafFlag": "1",
  "path":"r125",
  "name":"car"
},
  {
  "level": "2",
  "leafFlag": "0",
  "path":"p123/p345",
  "name":"apple"
},
 {
  "level": "2",
  "leafFlag": "1",
  "path":"p123/p095",
  "name":"banana"
},
{
  "level": "3",
  "leafFlag": "0",
  "path":"p123/p095/p546",
  "name":"grapes"
},
{
  "level": "2",
  "leafFlag": "1",
  "path":"r125/yhes",
  "name":"tata"
},

]



var expectedOutput = [
  {
    "level": "1",
    "leafFlag": "1",
    "path": "p123",
    "name": "food",
    "children": [
      {
        "level": "2",
        "leafFlag": "0",
        "path": "p123/p345",
        "name": "apple"
      },
      {
        "level": "2",
        "leafFlag": "1",
        "path": "p123/p095",
        "name": "banana",
        "children": [
          {
            "level": "3",
            "leafFlag": "0",
            "path": "p123/p095/p546",
            "name": "grapes"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "level": "1",
    "leafFlag": "1",
    "path": "r125",
    "name": "car",
    "children": [
      {
        "level": "2",
        "leafFlag": "1",
        "path": "r125/yhes",
        "name": "tata",
        "children": [
          {
            "level": "3",
            "leafFlag": "0",
            "path": "r125/yhes/sdie",
            "name": "Range Rover"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "level": "2",
        "leafFlag": "0",
        "path": "r125/theys",
        "name": "suzuki"
      }
    ]
  }
]


i tried the below code but not able to proceed further

private prepareTreeStructure = (inputJson) => {
    const treeFormat = (key, index, result) => {
      if (key.indexOf('/') === -1) {
        result = [...result, ...d[key]];
      } else {
        result.forEach((item, index) => {
          let splitKeyArray = key.split('/');
          splitKeyArray.forEach((splitItem, splitIndex) => {
            if (splitKeyArray.indexOf(item.path) !== -1) {
              if (!item['children']) {
                item['children'] = [];
              }
              if (splitKeyArray.length === splitIndex + 1) {
                result[index]['children'] = [...result[index]['children'], ...d[key]];
              }
            }
          });
          if (splitKeyArray.indexOf(item.path) !== -1) {
            if (!result[index]['children']) {
              result[index]['children'] = [];
            }
            result[index]['children'] = [...result[index]['children'], ...d[key]];
          }
        });
      }
      return result;
    }


    const d = inputJson.reduce((acc, ele) => {
      if (!acc[ele.path]) {
        acc[ele.path] = [];
      }
      acc[ele.path].push(ele);
      return acc;
    }, {});
    console.log('dddd  ', d);
    this.result = [];
    Object.keys(d).forEach((key, index) => {
      this.result = treeFormat(key, index, this.result);
      console.log('out ', this.result);
    })

  }
  
  prepareTreeStructure(inputJson);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this, works for an n number of levels:

```
var inputJson = [
  {
  "level": "1",
  "leafFlag": "1",
  "path":"p123",
  "name":"food"
},
  {
  "level": "1",
  "leafFlag": "1",
  "path":"r125",
  "name":"car"
},
  {
  "level": "2",
  "leafFlag": "0",
  "path":"p123/p345",
  "name":"apple"
},
 {
  "level": "2",
  "leafFlag": "1",
  "path":"p123/p095",
  "name":"banana"
},
{
  "level": "3",
  "leafFlag": "0",
  "path":"p123/p095/p546",
  "name":"grapes"
},
{
  "level": "2",
  "leafFlag": "1",
  "path":"r125/yhes",
  "name":"tata"
}
]
```

And the actual code:

```
var output = [];

inputJson = inputJson.sort((a, b) => (parseInt(a.level) > parseInt(b.level)) ? 1 : -1)
inputJson.forEach(v => {
    if (v.level == "1") {
    v.children = [];
    output.push(v);
  }
  else {
    pathValues = v.path.split("/");
    pathValues.pop();
    var node = null;
    var fullPath = "";
    pathValues.forEach(p => {
        fullPath = fullPath === "" ? p : fullPath + "/" + p;
        node = (node == null ? output : node.children).find(o => o.path === fullPath);
    })
    node.children = node.children || [];
    node.children.push(v);
  }
})

console.log(output)
```

See the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L984bo6x/8/

Comment: can you share something about looping it in a html table

Answer (score 0):

```js
var inputJson = [
  {
  "level": "1",
  "leafFlag": "1",
  "path":"p123",
  "name":"food"
},
  {
  "level": "1",
  "leafFlag": "1",
  "path":"r125",
  "name":"car"
},
  {
  "level": "2",
  "leafFlag": "0",
  "path":"p123/p345",
  "name":"apple"
},
 {
  "level": "2",
  "leafFlag": "1",
  "path":"p123/p095",
  "name":"banana"
},
{
  "level": "3",
  "leafFlag": "0",
  "path":"p123/p095/p546",
  "name":"grapes"
},
{
  "level": "2",
  "leafFlag": "0",
  "path":"r125/yhes",
  "name":"tata"
},

]


var expectedOutput = [
  {
    "level": "1",
    "leafFlag": "1",
    "path": "p123",
    "name": "food",
    "children": [
      {
        "level": "2",
        "leafFlag": "0",
        "path": "p123/p345",
        "name": "apple"
      },
      {
        "level": "2",
        "leafFlag": "1",
        "path": "p123/p095",
        "name": "banana",
        "children": [
          {
            "level": "3",
            "leafFlag": "0",
            "path": "p123/p095/p546",
            "name": "grapes"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "level": "1",
    "leafFlag": "1",
    "path": "r125",
    "name": "car",
    "children": [
      {
        "level": "2",
        "leafFlag": "1",
        "path": "r125/yhes",
        "name": "tata",
        "children": [
          {
            "level": "3",
            "leafFlag": "0",
            "path": "r125/yhes/sdie",
            "name": "Range Rover"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "level": "2",
        "leafFlag": "0",
        "path": "r125/theys",
        "name": "suzuki"
      }
    ]
  }
]


const groupByLevels = inputJson => {
 var levelsObj = {};
 inputJson.forEach(ele => {
  if (ele.level === "1") {
   if (!levelsObj["1"]) {
    levelsObj["1"] = [];
   }
   levelsObj["1"].push(ele)
  } else {
   if (!levelsObj[ele.level]) {
    levelsObj[ele.level] = {};
   }
   var parKey = ele.path.substr(0, ele.path.lastIndexOf('/'));
   if (!levelsObj[ele.level][parKey]) {
    levelsObj[ele.level][parKey] = [];
   }
   levelsObj[ele.level][parKey].push(ele);
  }
 })
 return levelsObj;
}

const mergeByGroups = (currLevelArr, groupJSON) => {
 currLevelArr.forEach(ele => {
  if (ele.leafFlag == "0") {
   return ele;
  }
  let nextLevel = parseInt(ele.level) + 1 + ""
  let nextLevelArr = groupJSON[nextLevel][ele.path];
  mergeByGroups(nextLevelArr, groupJSON)
  ele.children = nextLevelArr;
 })
}


const constructOutput = groupJSON => {
 mergeByGroups(groupJSON["1"], groupJSON);
 return groupJSON["1"];
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(constructOutput(groupByLevels(inputJson)), null, 4));
```